# Manual lifetime management, alternative to placement new

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a piece of low-level code with callbacks: `Init` and `Cleanup`, and others. I don't control the arguments of the callbacks. I chose to use a global variable for managing the state, say `class state`.

Here's a simple construct I can use:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<state> s;
void Init() {
    s = make_unique<state>();
}
void Cleanup() {
    s.reset();
}
```

It's simple and self explanatory. The main drawback: it uses the heap, which means that performance is sacrificed, and the allocation can fail.

Alternatively, I can use a construct similar to the following:

```cpp
alignas(state) unsigned char s_buf[sizeof(state)];
void Init() {
    state* s = new(s_buf) state;
}
void Cleanup() {
    state* s = reinterpret_cast<state*>(s_buf);
    s->~T();
}
```

Now I don't use the heap, but it's much uglier and more error prone, and I'm not even sure whether there's an undefined behavior lurking somewhere. I might be able to encapsulate it in a wrapper class, but there's so much that can go wrong.

Is there any common construct to achieve what I'm trying to do, i.e. having a `unique_ptr`-like class without the heap allocation?

Comment: How about using a `std::optional<state>`?

Comment: _"and I'm not even sure whether there's an undefined behavior lurking somewhere"_ IMO it lurks here `reinterpret_cast<state*>(s_buf);`.

Comment: Have you obtained evidence, through performance testing or profiling, that use of the heap actually does have an undue impact on performance of your program?

Comment: @spectras wow, that looks like a perfect solution! It's C++17 and up, but in this project C++17 is available. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the comment into an answer:

C++17 has the perfect tool for this: [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

It does exactly what you are doing, except it also tracks whether it currently has an object within the storage or not. Unless you are doing embedded and the additional size for the flag matters, it should be good:

```
#include <optional>

struct state {
    int foo;
};

static std::optional<state> currentState;

void Init() {
    currentState = state{ 42 };
}

void CleanUp() {
    currentState = std::nullopt;
}

void doStuff() {
    currentState->foo += 12;
}

void doStuffOnlyIfInitialized() {
    if (currentState) {
        currentState->foo += 12;
    }
}
```

Note that the code here will be happy if you call `Init` twice, or if you call `CleanUp` twice. If you want to prevent it, you can add an `assert(!currentState)` at beginning of `Init` and `assert(currentState)` at beginning of `CleanUp`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you *can* use a `std::unique_ptr` with a class with overloaded `new` and `delete` operators:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
struct global_type : T {
    static void* operator new (size_t) {
        static std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(global_type), alignof(global_type)> m_store;
        return &m_store;
    }

    static void operator delete(void*) {
    }
};

struct state {
    int foo;
};

std::unique_ptr<global_type<state>> ptr;

void Init() {
    ptr = std::make_unique<global_type<state>>();
    ptr->foo = 42;
}

void CleanUp() {
    ptr.reset();
}
```

`std::unique_ptr` will use the static overloads in `global_type` and therefore will not reach for any heap allocations and should be zero overhead.

Since `aligned_storage` is required to provide a storage fit to store the provided size and alignment, this should have no undefined behavior.

However, I'd recommend just using a `std::optional` as spectras mentioned in a comment unless there's a specific need for `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Maybe a placement new is need in the function `static void* operator new`

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Why?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin, `operator new` need only provide memory for the object. The compiler will insert a constructor call (i.e. placement new) at the memory this `operator new` returns.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR Thanks, now I know my previous comment is wrong

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the `std::optional` answer since it's so simple and straightforward. Your answer might be helpful in a project where C++17 is not available. Also, unlike the `std::optional` answer, your way limits the usage to a single variable of the `state` type.